# How do I filter in IMPORTRANGE using SEQUENCE and ARRAYFORMULA?

Tags: google-sheets-query, importrange, google-sheets-filter

I am having issues with including a **FILTER** option in my current working formula listed below:

`=QUERY (IMPORTRANGE("1n7qMGR9p8xD-8tyPIhfrcyBEsW8FAUMJMHmgxM7xIVI","Consultant Directory!A6:DF600"), ARRAYFORMULA("SELECT "&JOIN(", ","Col"&SEQUENCE(1,67))&", "&JOIN(", ", "Col"&SEQUENCE(1,3,108))),1)`

I've used the **SEQUENCE** because I only wanted some columns from the other Google Sheets. I would like to add a filter for **Col4** only to filter out a client's name while ascending from a cell option within the sheet.

An example to include is this:

`where Col4 contains 'Amanda' order by "&D2&" ASC"`